# How can I give different colors for class, enum, and interface names/identifiers in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

Is there a way to give distinct colors to classes, enums, and interfaces in VS Code for better differentiation? They all look the same, even the color of the variables look the same as the class name color.

```
export interface ITest { 
  property: string;
}

export enum TestEnum {
  test1,
  test2
}

export class Test {
  public property: string | undefined;
}
```

Comment: give the code in the screenshot as text as well. don't make me manually transcribe it to reproduce the setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Screenshot]

To achieve this, follow these steps:

1. Click on **File** in the top menu.
2. Choose **Preferences**, then select **Settings**.
3. In the top-right corner of the split editor, locate the icon just left of the "Open JSON Settings" button.
4. Click this icon to open the JSON settings editor.

Next, add the following code:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
  "textMateRules": [
    {
      "scope": "entity.name.type.enum",
      "settings": {
        "foreground": "#B8D7A3"
      }
    },
    {
      "scope": "entity.name.type",
      "settings": {
        "foreground": "#269da5"
      }
    },
    {
      "scope": "entity.name.type.interface",
      "settings": {
        "foreground": "#B8D7A3"
      }
    }
  ]
},
```

This configuration modifies the color of interfaces, enums, and classes using the provided color codes. you can change the color codes how you want.

Comment: typo?: `entity.name.type`. pretty sure `entity.name.type.class`.

Comment: Both options seem to work @starball

Answer (score 0):

You can use TextMate token scopes, but check also if the language support extension you're using supports semantic highlighting. If it does, then you can use [the standard token types](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/semantic-highlight-guide#standard-token-types-and-modifiers). Ex. in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson):

```json
"editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[your theme name here]": { // remove this theme wrapper to apply for all themes
        "rules": {
            "class": "#ff0000", // TODO
            "interface": "#ff0000", // TODO
            "enum": "#ff0000", // TODO
        },
    },
},
```

If not, then you need to figure out what TextMate token scopes are defined by your language support extension(s) for the tokens you want to colour, which you can do with the scope inspector tool. Use the `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette) to open the scope inspector widget and move the cursor over each of the tokens you are interested in, and then look at what tokens are defined for them. Ex. for TypeScript:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[your theme name here]": { // remove this theme wrapper to apply for all themes
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": "entity.name.type.enum",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#ff0000", // TODO
                },
            },
            {
                "scope": "entity.name.type.class",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#ff0000", // TODO
                },
            },
            {
                "scope": "entity.name.type.interface",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#ff0000", // TODO
                },
            },
        ],
    },
},
```